# Coloquialismos de la canción "Baracunátana" de Aterciopelados

Tags: vocabulario, coloquialismos, colombia, letras-de-canciones, música

Aterciopelados, rockeros colombianos, hicieron una famosa canción, ["Baracunátana"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bttFOOzcIHc), que parece estrenar una larga serie de palabras informales. Estas palabras describen a una mujer, pero ¿a qué van? ¿Son muy despectivas?

Al copiar el texto del librillo aquí, añadí las tildes y la puntuación (hasta en el título de la canción; me sorprendió ver que lo dejaron sin la tilde que requiere):

> Por eso, tú eres, garulla, retrechera, abeja, bergaja, fulera, guaricha, garosa, morronga, farisea, gorzobia, baracunata, cucharamí, baracunata, baracunátana -- sí señora.

Comment: ¿Has probado a buscarlas en el diccionario? Desde "garulla" hasta "farisea" todas aparecen bien en el [diccionario de la RAE](http://dle.rae.es/), bien en el [Diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/). A partir de ahí ya parece que empieza a desvariar. Un par de ellas aparecen marcadas como despectivas, el resto son simplemente coloquiales.

Comment: Baracunatana no la escribieron los Aterciopelados, la interpretaron haciéndole una nueva versión a su estilo (la original era vallenato) y le agregaron la parte final: "por eso tú eres guaricha..." pero no son los autores.

Comment: Explicada por el autor de la canción, cordial saludo https://youtu.be/7KLL4gEegWU

Comment: En realidad la primera persona que hace referencia a esta palabra fue Lizandro Meza, Genero Vallenato

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Todas se usan con carácter despectivo hacia una mujer. Sobre si son muy despectivas, bueno, por supuesto tienen distintos grados, pero van desde llamar a la mujer "falsa" a "guarra/libertina".

El propio título de la canción, [Baracunatana](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Baracunatana.php),  es un término despectivo, y eso no puede sino establecer el tono para todos los otros:

> Dícese de la mujer que es de dudosa procedencia, o que se dedica a la vida fácil, tienes muchos amoríos, etc.

Podrías intentar alabar a alguien al decirle que es "abeja" u "hormiguita", ya que estos insectos son muy laboriosos, aunque en este caso "abeja" parece ser usado de otra manera (quizá como, "ese bicho que no me deja en paz y que no quiero que me pique"?)

Ten en cuenta que al ser coloquialismos, no todos los términos estarán "oficialmente" recogidos en el diccionario. La mejor explicación que yo he encontrado proviene de [esta internauta](https://mx.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061031082152AAOMHT8)

> Soy colombiana y te puedo decir que básicamente todos se refieren a la misma cosa, con pequeñas variaciones... una mujer fácil, infiel [...]
>
> honestamente no los conozco todos
>
> abeja es...astuta
>
> bergaja... jodida, complicada, mañosa
>
> guaricha ... algo así como prostituta
>
> retrechera...creo que es mañosa también....
>
> Como sea, **en la canción todos son insultos para una mujerzuela**.....baracunatana

Cabe también destacar (aunque habría que contrastar) la aportación de otro de los usuarios en el mismo hilo, que dice

> **Baracunata es una palabra creada por Aterciopelados**, según un amigo el míos colombiano, y significa algo como "perra".

De ser cierto, explicaría porqué algunos términos puedan ser imposibles de encontrar en el diccionario. El autor se toma una licencia poética para crearlos (notable la dificultad para encontrar referencias a *cucharamí* que no sean dentro de esta canción y esas variaciones finales baracuta -baracunátana)

Comment: Hay que corregir la parte que dice que la palabra baracunatana la inventaron los aterciopelados. Ellos sacaron esa canción en 1996 como un _cover_ de la original de Lisandro Meza de 1981. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisandro_Meza

Comment: **Retrechero, ra**: http://dle.rae.es/?id=WKBV94U : 1. adj. coloq. Que con artificios disimulados y mañosos trata de eludir la confesión de la verdad o el cumplimiento de lo debido.

**2. adj. coloq. Que tiene mucho atractivo.** *Mujer retrechera*. Ojos retrecheros.

Answer (score 2):

Puedo aportar que "fulera" es usada en lenguaje coloquial (lunfardo) con frecuencia en Argentina se refiere a una mujer fea o desarreglada

Answer (score 2):

Guaricha just means mujer in the Muisca language (the one spoken by the aboriginal inhabitants of what is Bogota today.) It was later adopted by the Spaniards as a derogatory term to refer to a woman. By the way, the Muisca term for man is "guache", which also adopted by the Spaniard to refer a man with bad manners.

References:
- https://www.civico.com/bogota/noticias/palabras-muiscas-que-usamos-los-bogotanos-sin-saberlo
- http://muysca.cubun.org/Categor%C3%ADa:Diccionario

Comment: Que grosero negativizar una palabra de esta forma. Gracias por el dato.

Answer (score 1):

Retrechero/a = Mal agradecido.

Abeja = Que tiene viveza, astuto.

Bergajo/a = Se usa sobre todo para referirse a un niño/a mal criado.

Fulera = Que es fea.

Guaricha = Mujer promiscua.

Garoso/a = Esta palabra se usa cuando alguien es glotón pero en el contexto de la letra hace referencia a el apetito sexual.

Morronga = Mojigato.

Farisea = Que es falsa.

Garulla/Gorzobia = No creo que tengan algún equivalente solo son insultos.

Dudo que en alguna región de Colombia usen las palabras baracunata y cucharamí, eso no lo sé.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Es posible aportar alguna referencia sobre los términos menos conocidos? No es que dude de que estés en lo cierto, pero así si llega alguien diciendo que significan otra cosa, tu aportación tendrá cierta evidencia de que al menis en una región en particular significan eso. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

lo otro es que baracunatana , lo mas seguro es que se refiere a una mujer que le guste la bareta o mariguana, lo otro es que guaricha es un termino indígena que fue tergiversado con la llegada de los españoles , la guaricha es una mujer guerrera que se les enfrentó a los españoles y peleó en su contra , era además una princesa, hija de un cacique y que era muy bella.También se entendía que la guaricha era una mujer hermosa. Pero ahora, una guaricha es una mujer burda, que habla mal y no es educada. En todo caso, muy alejado a una guerrera o mujer hermosa.

Alguien garoso si es glotón, pero aquí también se usa el termino hacia la promiscuidad. Retrechera es una mujer sexualmente muy activa y que no cobra.
Garulla es una mala persona, un ladrón, una persona de muy bajo nivel, mal
educado, burdo...

Además quiero aclarar que la canción no es de los Aterciopelados, sino un *cover* que ellos hicieron. En esta página resumen un poco sobre ella: https://www.facebook.com/leeporgusto/posts/baracunatana-es-una-canci%C3%B3n-compuesta-por-el-m%C3%BAsico-colombiano-leonidas-plaza-id/1069429309748252/

Comment: Ten en cuenta que el formato adecuado puede hacer tu respuesta más fácil de entender. Pon algún punto y aparte.

Answer (score 0):

La canción Baracunatana de Aterciopelados publicada en 1996 es una adaptación de la canción Baracunatana de Lisandro Meza publicada en 1981, que fue escrita por Leónidas Plazas.

Según Andrea Echeverri la armaron de varias versiones según la recordaban. Incluso, en algún momento cantaban "Paracunata", antes de enterarse que la original era con "B".

La mayoría de los términos fueron agregados por la versión de Aterciopelados, y pueden encontrarse en la rae: "[garulla](https://dle.rae.es/garulla)", "[retrechera](https://dle.rae.es/retrechero)", "[abeja](https://dle.rae.es/abeja)", "[fulera](https://dle.rae.es/fulero)", "[garosa](https://dle.rae.es/garoso)", "[morronga](https://dle.rae.es/morrongo)", "[farisea](https://dle.rae.es/fariseo)".

Esto nos deja "bergaja" y "gorzobia" de la versión de Aterciopelados. Y por otro lado "cucharam(b)i" y por supuesto "baracunata" de ambas versiones.

La palabra "bergaja" probablemente sea "[vergaja](https://dle.rae.es/vergajo)". Siendo común confundir "v" con "b" en el español latino. Tengo que decir que coloquialmente en Colombia se solía utilizar el termino para referirnos a un escupitajo, y en general a algo desagradable (se pueden imaginar que tiene que ver con "verga" y lo que implica decirlo de alguien). Por otro lado, la palabra "gorzobia" es un insulto colombiano que significa algo así cómo "indeseable", "repugnante".

Luego tenemos "cucharambi", que Aterciopelados cambió a "cucharami".

Leónidas Plazas utiliza [Jeringonza](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerigonza) para derivar sus palabras. En este caso reordenándola y reemplazando las silabas por sonidos similares.
Según el escritor la palabra "cucharambi" significa "bironcha", que significa "homosexual". Según explica Lisandro Meza, le está diciendo "lesbiana".

Lo que nos deja "baracunata".

Leónidas Plazas aprendió su Jeringonza en Maicao, donde insertaban "cuna", "cune", "cuni", "cuno" en las palabras para confundir a los Venezuelans. Por ejemplo "costecuneño" significa "costeño". Así, "baracunata" significa "barata".

En cuento a la versión escrita por Leónidas Plazas, encontramos unos términos que desaparecieron en la versión de aterciopelados: "turocunocolo locurucutu". Que, según el autor, significa "culo loco".

Referencias:

- [Un encuentro baracunátana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E6jso_eARkA)
- [Baracunatana - Lisandro Meza | Detrás de la Canción Shock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZKef-ZqsNc)
- [Baracunatana, una historia de drogas y desamor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KLL4gEegWU).